# How to perform retrieval of data from SQLite without callback function

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

Can I retrieve data from sqlite database without callback?

I need something like this, but it is not working

```
var querwy = "SELECT * FROM stock";
var result=$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, querwy, []);
alert(result.rows.item(0).name);
```

instead of this which is working

```
var querwy = "SELECT * FROM stock";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, querwy, []).then(function(result){
alert(result.rows.item(0).name);
},function(error){
alert('error');
});
```

I really need to remove the callback function.

Comment: The code seems to be wrong syntactically ...

Comment: yeah thanks, i just edited it

Comment: The callback is a useful element. In this case when the db operation ends, the callback is called. The time between the request and the callback is time the system uses to retrieve the data from the db. 
Anyway the retrieval of data must occur, and it seems that the code you use does not handle the retrieval in case of assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If using cordovaSQLite is not a constraint for you, then you could use [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php), which is included **by default** in every Php version higher than 5.3
This example works:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
   function __construct()
   {
      $this->open('test.db');
   }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
   echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
   echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}

$sql = "SELECT * from STOCK";

echo "<pre>";
$ret = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
   //Show as columns
   //echo "ID = ". $row['ID'] . "\n";
   print_r( $row ) . "\n"
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
```

Maybe you can do something similar.